# KnockoutJs submit binding starts inifinite loop

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to submit my form to a rest service using knockout. After pressing the `submit` button the form goes into an infinite loop until the browser crashes. Can't really understand what's going on here.

Javascript:

```
var viewModel;
var Subscription = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.Name = ko.observable('');
    self.Email = ko.observable('');

    self.submitForm = function () {
        var viewModelJs = ko.toJS(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(viewModel));

        $.ajax('/umbraco/surface/newsletter/AddSubscription', {
            data: viewModelJs,
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("sent");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                if (window.console && console.log) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    };
};

$(function () {
    viewModel = new Subscription();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

And here is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" data-bind="submit: $root.submitForm">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="Name">Nombre</label>
        <div class="controls">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { placeholder = "Nombre", data_bind = "value: Name" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- A couple more controls here -->

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

**ko.toJS** preserves functions and like you are using a jquery function and it will run all functions on the data object (viewModelJS). This in turn causes the infinite loop.

you could use the mapping object and ignore the function like this

```
  var viewModelJs = ko.mapping.toJS(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(viewModel), {
  ignore: ['submitForm']});
```

Comment: Ended up using `var viewModelJs = ko.toJSON(viewModel);`

Comment: see this issue in github: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/251   it should be fixed in the next version of knockout.